Fitting OLS with constraint on the betas
Suppose my model looks like $y=\beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_3$, but there's a catch: I want to enforce $\beta_1=\beta_3$. How do I do this, in both frequentist and Bayesian setup? Specifically for the Bayesian route, I am using pymc, is there any way to achieve this?

Why do you want to do this?

Similar question.

Another https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/523922/

$y=\beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_3$ with the constraint $\beta_1 = \beta_3$ can be expressed as
$$\begin{align}
y&=\beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_1 x_3 \\
&= \beta_1 (x_1 + x_3) + \beta_2x_2
\end{align}$$
So just make a new column that is the sum $x_1 + x_3$.

Another option is to use a program for structural equation modeling (SEM; e.g., the lavaan package in R), which allows you to impose various linear and non-linear constraints on regression parameters directly (including equality constraints).
One advantage of the SEM approach is that it allows you to test (via model fit testing) whether the constraint of equal regression slopes is reasonable for your data.
